# dot self notation in nsxmlparser

Tags: iphone, ios, nsxmlparser

I was just reading an answer to a different question on nsxmlparsing.. and in it the guy was saying you should use self. notation for better memory management... what dose this mean?

I have left this out of initializing my dictionary should I have it in? how dose it help or not help?

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict 
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Row"]) 
    {
        ICRow = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:attributeDict];
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Rows"]) {
        self.ICRows = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:8];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bar = self.foo;
```

is just a shorthand notation for

```
bar = [self foo];
```

and

```
self.foo = bar;
```

is shorthand for

```
[self setFoo:bar];
```

In terms of memory management **this just means that the specific setters and getters are invoked**, whereas

```
foo = bar
```

would simply assign the value (i.e. mostly just copy the pointer).

Say you have a retained property

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) FooType *foo;
//...
@synthesize foo;
```

then the setter might look like

```
- (void) setFoo:(FooType*)x
{
 [x retain];
 [foo release];
 foo = x;
}
```

Now if you do a

```
FooType *newFoo = [[FooType alloc] init];
[self setFoo:newFoo];
// or self.foo = newFoo
```

Everything would be allright, since your previously allocated object is released and the new object is retained properly. If you instead just did a

```
foo = newFoo;
```

without thinking about to release the old and retain the new object, you would be leaking memory or worse...

Comment: thanks for the detailed response, another question related to your response: what difference dose it make if I am now using ARC?

Comment: When you are using ARC, the compiler tries to insert a [foo release]/[foo retain] whenever it sees it fit and by some algorithm judges that there should be a actually a call to release/retain. ARC is, however, **not** a garbarge collector. While ARC works quite well and does a good job, there might be circumstances where it fails miserably (see Apple's WWDC 2011 videos on ARC, available on iTunes). When you are using ARC, just forget about retains and releases and dealloc until you figure something is wrong (e.g. by Instruments showing you strange leaks).

Comment: okay cool thanks for that. :) I think i get it.. worst come to worst I will check for memory leaks with the xcode tools and pick it up there. :) hanks again.

Comment: Sorry, please re-read my comment, I had to delete and recreate it because I sometimes just type too fast ;)